# value of my int variable changes arbitrarily after function executes

Tags: c

I'm currently in the middle of one of my coding assignments, in which We create a gameboard for a game of reversi (Othello), give it some initial condition, and check for legality of moves.

The code begins by asking the user for the size of the board (sidelength) and uses one function to initialize the board and another to print it.

My code works fine for boardDim = 4 and boardDim = 6, however when I enter 8, after the function responsible for initializing the board executes all its statements, the value of boardDim jumps to something like 21568 and that leads to a segmentation error Note: lab handout says we can assume that sidelength of board will never exceed 26
Thanks for reading!

Here is my code:

```
void InitBoard(char reversiBoard[][26], const int a) {

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {

            if ((i == (a / 2 - 1)) && (j == (a / 2 - 1))) {
                reversiBoard[i][j] = 'W';
            }
            else if ((i == (a / 2 - 1)) && (j == a / 2)) {
                reversiBoard[i][j] = 'B';
            }
            else if ((i == a / 2) && (j == (a / 2 - 1))) {
                reversiBoard[i][j] = 'B';
            }
            else if ((i == a / 2) && (j == a / 2)) {
                reversiBoard[i][j] = 'W';
            }
            else {
                reversiBoard[i][j] = 'U';
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

void printBoardCurr(char reversiBoard[][26], const int a) {

    char alphabet[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

    printf("  ");

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        printf("%c", (alphabet[i]));
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
        printf("%c ", (alphabet[j]));

        for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
            printf("%c", reversiBoard[j][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

int main(void) {

    int boardDim = 0;
    printf("Enter the board dimension: ");
    scanf(" %d", &boardDim);

    char reversiBoard[boardDim][boardDim];
    InitBoard(reversiBoard, boardDim);
    printBoardCurr(reversiBoard, boardDim);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void InitBoard(char reversiBoard[][26], const int a)` is wrong if you do not enter `26` as dimension. You can use `void InitBoard(const int a, char reversiBoard[][a])`. The `26` is not the maximum size, it is the exact size of the array.

Comment: what is it with all these people leaving `{` characters hanging off the end of lines?  It's awful - put it on a new line on its own, just like the closing `}`!  That character marks the beginning of a scope block.  It has NOTHING to do with an `if`, `while`, function declaration, etc, and should not be left with it.  Left like this they get deleted, mismatched, lost off the end of the screen and many other annoying problems.  Please, don't do it.

Comment: Sidenote: you don't need the `alphabet` array at all.

Comment: Why is `reversiBoard` a local variable if all your functions need to use it? Just make it a global variable, and set the size to the maximum size (26 by 26). That'll make everything much nicer since you're not passing it on the stack everywhere.

Comment: @mch This surprises me. AFAIK arrays are always passed by address, never by value. But, I guess you are on the right track. The function `InitBoard()` will always assume "inner dimension" 26 where `main()` makes size on request. Thus, the pointer arithmetic in `InitBoard()` will fail.

Comment: Thank you so much! totally worked! If you wouldn't mind could  you explain why my original code was wrong? I imagine it has something to do with how memory is handled but I do not know nearly enough to ID the source of my issue.

Comment: @Eric These multi-dimensional arrays in C are a little bit dangerous in exact the situation you have. Why not using a single dimensional array with size `a * a` and doing the row/col. calculation by yourself? cell[i, j] ... `reversiBoard[i * boardDim + j]` if i is row and j is column-

Comment: @Scheiff your approach is totally valid, however as the course generally expects the students to follow what is taught, the Teacher's Assistent might get grumpy at avoiding the use of a 2D array

Comment: @Eric OK, I see. In this case, you have to change the array allocation in `main()` to `char reversiBoard[boardDim][26]` or the pointer arithmetic in `InitBoard()` will fail for any `boardDim` != 26.

Comment: @Scheff there is only pass by value in C, so in this case the address of the array will be passed by value to the function. But you are correct, the problem is the inner dimension, if it is the wrong value, the pointer arithmetic is wrong.

Comment: @mch Well, that's why the _address_ of array is passed by _value_. (C cannot have been changed so much since I learnt it decades ago.)

Comment: So the solution is to pass the dimension first and use the variable for the dimension of the 2D array: http://ideone.com/Pr8mSC

Comment: @mch The parameter for the 2D array will always consume the size of one pointer which is always equal regardless the type the pointer is pointing too. (even if it is a void pointer which points to nothing).